# ListView item as a progress bar

Tags: list, listview, xamarin.android, progress-bar, listadapter

I was wondering if someone can maybe help me with the following intent:

I created an app which simply displays a table. It shows a table head and beyond that a list view which contains several items.

Is it possible, that if one clicks on one of these items, a progress bar is shown which loads smoothely in a certain time interval (lets say 30 seconds) from left to right?

Please see my screenshot below, maybe it's easier to understand what I am trying to do:

[image: Screenshot of goal]

Finally, I don't know if it helps, but let me attach some code as well. I shortened it a little, if something is missing for understanding (like the list class) or if I removed to much, please let me know:

```
public class TableActivity : Activity
{
    ListView lv;
    ListAdapter adapter = null;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        //...
        lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.geraeteListView);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.List, geraeteliste.CurrentGeraeteliste, Intent.GetStringExtra("ServerIP"))
        {
            parentActivity = this
        };
        lv.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    private async void OnItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (geraeteliste.CurrentGeraeteliste[e.Position].bespielt == "J") return;
        //…
        await Task.Delay(0);
    } 
}

public class ListAdapter : ArrayAdapter
{
    //...
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.List, parent, false);
        }
        //...
        v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.typeImageView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.numberTextView).Text = Geraetelist[position].geraeteplatz;
        v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.descriptionTextView).Text = Geraetelist[position].geraeteinformation;
        ImageView iv = v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.bspImageView);
        iv.SetImageResource(Geraetelist[position].bespielt == "N" ? Resource.Drawable.greenPoint : Resource.Drawable.redPoint);
        //…
        return v;        
    }
}
```

Can anyone maybe give me a short hint or something? How can I implement such a progress bar for every item on click?^^ Would be really happy for every helping effort.

Thanks in advance for every answer,

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible, that if one clicks on one of these items, a progress bar is shown which loads smoothly in a certain time interval (lets say 30 seconds) from left to right?

If you want to display progressbar when click Listview item, I do one sample for you, you can take a look:

1.Declare ListView layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ListView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2.Declare list row layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:visibility="invisible"

            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

3.Define ListView Adapter

```
public class Post
{      
    public string title { get; set; }
    public bool isselect { get; set; }
   
}

public class CusotmListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Post>
{
    Activity context;
    List<Post> list;

    public CusotmListAdapter(Activity _context, List<Post> _list)
    : base()
    {
        this.context = _context;
        this.list = _list;
    }

    public override Post this[int position]
    {
        get { return list[position]; }

    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return list.Count; }

    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;

    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;

        // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        // otherwise create a new one
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItemRow, parent, false);

        Post item = this[position];
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = item.title;
        if(item.isselect==true)
        {
            view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1).Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }


        return view;
    }

}
```

4.Setting ListView Adapter

```
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
     {
       private ListView listview;
       List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
       private CusotmListAdapter adapter;
       private int oldposition = -1;
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

        posts.Add(new Post() { title = "title 1", isselect = false });
        posts.Add(new Post() { title = "title 2", isselect = false });
        posts.Add(new Post() { title = "title 3", isselect = false });
        posts.Add(new Post() { title = "title 4", isselect = false });
        posts.Add(new Post() { title = "title 5", isselect = false });
        posts.Add(new Post() { title = "title 6", isselect = false });
        posts.Add(new Post() { title = "title 7", isselect = false });
        posts.Add(new Post() { title = "title 8", isselect = false });
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView);
        listview.ItemClick+= OnListItemClick;
        adapter= new CusotmListAdapter(this, posts);
        listview.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void OnListItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(oldposition!=-1)
        {
            Post p1 = adapter[oldposition];
            p1.isselect = false;
        }
        oldposition = e.Position;
        Post p = adapter[e.Position];
        p.isselect = true;
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

      }
     }
```

### Update

You can change some code in CusotmListAdapter GetView event:

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;

        // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        // otherwise create a new one
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItemRow, parent, false);

        Post item = this[position];

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = item.title;
        ProgressBar p = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
        p.Max = 100;
        p.Progress = 100;
        //p.IncrementProgressBy(-10);
        if(item.isselect==true)
        {
            view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                while (p.Progress > 0)
                {
                    p.Progress -= 20;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            })).Start();
        }
        else
        {
            view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1).Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }


        return view;
    }
```

Then please look at the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Cherry Bu - MSFT and thank you so much for your answer and your sample. Okay, I was more thinking displaying that ProgressBar in the background of one row, but as this works as well, I am fine with displaying that ProgressBar in the Bottom of each row. Unfortunately, this was only the half of my question, now comes the difficult part^^: How can I make it, that if one clicks on a specific row, the ProgressBar of the row clicked loads smoothely in a certain time interval (e.g. 30 seconds) from 100% (right) to 0% (left)?

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you are missing some knowledge on ListViews. This [Xamarin university course](https://github.com/XamarinUniversity/AND110/tree/ace0df6b09fe20510d05bd1278c12fd464c6fdcc) has some examples and a video that explain the different components.

But basically, you can put your `background progress bar` as a `View` in your `row` AXML layout file, and depending on the value of the `Progress` property, that view can change widths.

Let me know if you have questions

Comment: Yeah, I am really sorry as I am only student trainee end therefore a bit lacking of knowledge. I now put the ProgressBar as a `View` in my `Row.axml` file. I can change the width via `SetProgress()` (I have an Adapter (`var pb = v.FindViewById; pb.SetProgress();`) and did something like `RunOnUiThread(() => {adapter.progress = 25; adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();});` but how can I change the width smoothely within a certain time interval? Do I have to create a `System.Timers.Timer` / just call the `SetProgress()` every ms hoping that the eye is slow enough that it seems to load smoothely?